# Cufflinks Pivot chart axis name is not coming

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, cufflinks

I am using cufflinks to plot a pivot chart.My code is given below.

```
CHIP_CURRENT_PVT_EX = pd.pivot_table(df_cur_funct_mode1,index = 'Temp(deg)',columns = 'Device_ID',values = 'Chip_Cur(uAmp)')
CHIP_CURRENT_PVT_EX['SPEC_TYP']= 192
CHIP_CURRENT_PVT_EX.iplot(title='CHIP CURRENT vs TEMPERATURE')
```

The plot is coming as expected ,but the axis names are not coming.May I know where I went wrong.

My X axis name is "Temp(deg)" and Y axis name is "Chip_Cur(uAmp)" and I need the title to come in the middle

Please see my plot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are not automatically displayed, you would need to set the x-axis title and y-axis title from the layout attributes, respectively.

```
df.iplot(layout=dict(title='CHIP CURRENT vs TEMPERATURE', xaxis_title='Temp(deg)', yaxis_title='Chip_Cur(uAmp)'))
```

[image]